# Cannot get "system.peers" from AWS Keyspaces when using Shared VPC and Endpoint from diffrent account

Tags: cassandra, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc, amazon-keyspaces, vpc-endpoint

We have 2 AWS accounts(111111111111, 222222222222). First account have VPS and Endpoint for cassandra service. This VPC share to the second account.

How can get correct list of system.peers from aws keyspaces service from the second account?

AWS user was created in the second account with permissions like:

```
"Action": [
    "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
    "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints"
],
"Resource": "*"
and
AmazonKeyspacesFullAccess
```

Using this user, I have access to connect to any keyspace in the second account.
But a cannot get peer list from keyspace system:
Keyspaces_user-at-22222222@cqlsh:system> SELECT * FROM system.peers;

```
 peer | data_center | host_id | preferred_ip | rack | release_version | rpc_address | schema_version | tokens
------+-------------+---------+--------------+------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------

(0 rows)
```

If I use other user(Keyspaces_user-at-111111111111), that created in first account with the same permissions - I have to get this list, but i cannot see my created keyspaces because in the first account I haven't any created keystaces.

As additional, I add permissions for user  Keyspaces_user-at-22222222:

```
"Action": "cassandra:*",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": [
      "arn:aws:cassandra:us-east-1:111111111111:/keyspace/system*"
]
```

but it doesn't help

MB I missed VPC Endpoint policies configuration.
Current VPC Endpoint policy:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How did you create and bind your VPCE endpoints to your keyspace? Follow this tutorial with more details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/vpc-endpoints-tutorial.configure-ec2-instance.html